# create zoom in and zoom out tool button on google map

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to create zoom in and zoom out tool in my website for zooming on Google map.I tried to zoom in or zoom out on any particular location on the map after selecting the tool that i have created, now wanted to zoom in or zoom out on the map by selecting the tool how is it possible any help will be great for me and this is my button code

```
<button name="button" value="" type="button" id="zoomIn"></button>
<button name="button" value="" type="button" id="zoomOut"></button>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="zoom.js"></script>
<script>
    var mapCanvas;

  function initialize() {
    mapCanvas = document.getElementById('mapviewer');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.61, 77.20),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  function zoom_in(){
      mapCanvas.zoomIn();
  }
  function zoom_out(){
      mapCanvas.zoomOut();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the map code? which you want to zoom in and out?

Comment: @MarmiK i just pasted my map code check it

Comment: still I am not able to make this code working in my fiddle, `jsFiddle`[http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/tt3f56kp/] please make if working and post the updated fiddle back..

Answer (score 1):

Try this by change `mapCanvas.zoomIn();` into

```
map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);
```